# Save all attachments of all tagged messages with mutt

Tags: email, mutt

I have around 100 messages in a mailbox in mutt, each of which has an attachment. (These are scanned documents sent by a printer.) I would like to save all attachments of all these messages in a folder.

Is there a convenient way to do so within `mutt`?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you're aware: This is not really a mutt question unless you are determined to solve it with mutt. In that case, good luck! But if I recall correctly, mutt is just another mbox mail file format mail reader. And in that case, you can expand your horizons.

Comment: @RichardT: Thanks! yes, I'm sure it could be done with other tools. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some non-obvious way to do this with mutt as I already use it, e.g., macros or similar. Thanks for your recommendation of an alternative way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer is:

Use ripMIME.

The man page for ripmime says:

> ripMIME  is  a command line tool used to aid in the extraction of
> email borne attachments to files which can  be  processed  using
> other  UNIX tools.   ripMIME  supports both the RFC MIME standards as
> well as being able to behave according to various MUA 'features' which
> are often used as exploitation holes.

Of course, it'll likely be a little more complex than just that.

Since you tagged your emails, perhaps start by asking mutt to make a copy of these tagged messages into a single mbox to make the set of them more convenient.

I use ripmime one email at a time, however you'll probably want to use the --maibox option.

ripMIME is feature-rich! Enjoy!